# postgresql explain analyze from sql file?

Tags: postgresql

I had wrote a long query for postgresql, and I want to use postgresql explain ANALYZE to find out runnig time / parallel workers information about that query.
I can run that sql command by using

```
psql -d database -f myquery.sql
```

but I don't know how to explan/analyze that sql file in command.
and because it is a really long query , it's hard to paste in psql console.
so , is there any other way to run explain/analyze from the sql file ?

Comment: Edit the file and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` immediately before the `SELECT`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cat` to create a command you pass to `psql`. For example like this:

```
psql -d database -c "explain analyze $( cat myquery.sql )"
```

Editing a file and adding those statements at the beginning are an option too.